# Remove the bar at the top of Loginview for formatting

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm making a webform using a `LoginView`, the problem is that because the control includes a grey bar telling you what type of control it is it throws of correctly formatting the page (it has `LoginView1` at the top).

Is there a way to hide this on the `LoginView` as the `contentPlaceholder` does an excellent job for this.

I've found that you can remove the ID, but that seems like a hack as it stops programatic access

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood your question but....

The 'grey bar telling you what type of control it is' only shows up if you are looking at the page in 'design view' in your IDE (are you using Visual Studio?).
Once you run the page this label is not visible.

It is very common for pages that have dynamic/server-side content to 'not look right' when you are looking at them in 'design view'.

Little things like the label/grey bar you are talking about are just there to help you work on the page when it is not populated with the dynamic content.

As a result of this, I find that 99.9% of the time I use 'source view' in my IDE because as your page content becomes more dynamic, the 'design view' becomes more useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a property to control this (can't find one on MSDN), but I'd think you could just iterate through the Controls property of the LoginView and hide that panel/label/whatever.